# Libgdx + android.app.Service, how to?

Tags: java, service, libgdx

So i want to do certain things always run in background. I've read that to do that i need to use android.app.Service, so i could not find anything that explain how to do this with libgdx so i did this.

on the AndroidLauncher I added this line

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyServices.class));
```

MyServices.class extends Service and on onStartCommand() i added a new thread that has a infinite loop, like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
    new Thread(){
        private long startTime;
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= 1000){
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("running");
                }
            }
        };
    }.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The app keeps printing "running" every second even when the app is not running, but I feel like this is not the correct way to do this, can someone please enlighten me? Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question? You followed the directions and it's working, so what's the problem?

Comment: I did not follow any directions, thats why im asking if is the right approach

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, I am trying to implement :

this is what you are looking for, [Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder)

Edit:

1. Add service to your Androidmanifest.xml file
2. Bind Service to Activity or Start service

bind service mean if activity stop also service stop, example a music player,

starting service, will not stop, like a service where it give notifications even if application is not running.

There is also a permission for on boot, you need to implement so that the service start when your phone boot up.

happy coding.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30865176)